# How can I use DatePicker on a Kotlin Desktop App using jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

Here's my build.gradle.kts which is pretty much generated

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.vladdrummer"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}
kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        named("commonMain") {
            resources.srcDirs("resources")
            // other parts
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.material3)

                implementation("com.darkrockstudios:mpfilepicker:1.0.0")
                implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6")
                implementation("com.fazecast:jSerialComm:[2.0.0,3.0.0)")
                implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Exe)
            packageName = "entertainment_desktop"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

So I added following to the gradle to be able to use DatePicker which is in material3

```
@OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.material3)
```

But when I try to use it in code - it doesn't let me :
[image]

But DatePicker should be in desktop library too :
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-core/blob/jb-main/compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/DatePicker.kt

Comment: try to put ``` implementation(compose.material3)``` in Common Source Set As well.